# (Jest/Enzyme/React) How to assert that throttled function inside change handler has been called?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I need to assert that `SearchInputActions.onSearchActivated(value)` is called when something is written in an input.  It is a callback which is in change handler `handleChange`. I've been trying to create to mocks - one for `handleChange` and one for `search` but it did not work either. I am using jest and enzyme for tests.

```
const SearchInput = () => {
    const search = throttle(event => {
        const value = event.target.value;

        SearchInputActions.onSearchActivated(value);
    });

    const handleChange = event => {
        event.persist();
        search(event);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <SomeChildComponent />
            <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Test:

```
it('should dispatch search action', async () => {
    const tree = mount(<SearchInput />);
    const spySearch = jest.spyOn(SearchInputActions, 'onSearchActivated');
    SearchInputActions.onSearchActivated.mockImplementation(() => {})
    
    tree.find('input').simulate('change', {target: value: 'test'}});
    
    expect(spySearch).toBeCalled();
}
```

Comment: The simple answer is: you just don't. Why would you? You should only unit test the things that are visible to the outside world, and in your example there is none. This may sound like an excuse but think about it this way: if you change the name or the implementation of either of those functions tomorrow, will anyone notice? No, there is no way of observing the effects of that change, so there is no desired behaviour you want to test for.

Comment: true, but it is a simpler version of what I do in a project where the equivalent of `formatValue` dispatches an action and I need to check if it dispatches the proper one. I am not able to check any visible output of this

Comment: Ah okay, but in that case you should mock wherever the action is dispatched to instead.

Comment: @biziclop, I updated the code based on your advice. But it does not work either. Received number of calls is 0

Comment: now I am wondering, maybe the reason is `event.persist()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: Because the callback function was throttled (lodash throttle) I needed to add jest.useFakeTimers(); Final code looks like this:

```
jest.useFakeTimers();

it('should dispatch search action', async () => {
    const tree = mount(<SearchInput />);
    const spySearch = jest.spyOn(SearchInputActions, 'onSearchActivated');

    SearchInputActions.onSearchActivated.mockImplementation(() => {})
    
    tree.find('input').simulate('change', {target: value: 'test'}});
    
    expect(spySearch).not.toBeCalled();

    jest.runAllTimers();

    expect(spySearch).toBeCalled();

    SearchInputActions.onSearchActivated.mockRestore();
}
```